# How to join model with attribute of other (related) model (plotting data from child)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-models

In an app using the chartkick gem:

I have the following database table relations:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :games
  contains id, email
end

class Game < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :levels
  belongs_to :user
  #contains id, user_id, name

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :levels
end

class Level < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :game
  #contains id, score and game_id
end
```

How do i plot the score acquired by each player?
And then the average score acquired by each player each game?

I want to do something like:

```
<%= column_chart Level.group(:user.email).sum(:score) %>
```

I managed to do:

```
<%= column_chart Level.group(:game_id).sum(:score) %>
```

The entire code can be found [here](https://github.com/devdavidkarlsson/HighscoreBackend)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"How do i plot the score acquired by each player?"

First add this to User:

```
has_many :levels, :through => :games
```

Then get the total score per player with:

```
 User.includes(:levels).group(:email).sum(:score)
```

---

"And then the average score acquired by each player each game?"

```
User.includes(:levels).group(:email, :game_id).average(:score)
```

This returns a hash with a tuple (email, game_id) as key and the average as value. Grouping by email is only to be able to get some user identification back in the results but there should be a nicer way to do it somehow.

Answer (score 0):

You can join the tables using includes,

> arel = Level.includes(:user, :game)

Then use appropriate query as you want to,

> arel = arel.group('user.email')

Comment: :user, :game is never declared what are they to be?

Comment: You have declared two models, User and Game. :user and :game refer to there table names in the database. To be specific they must be users and games I guess.

Comment: <%arel = Level.includes(:users, :games)%>
 <%= column_chart arel.group('user.email').sum(:score) %>
 The last line throws:
Association named 'users' was not found on Level; perhaps you misspelled it?

Comment: At first, I would suggest you to do this in your action rather than in the view itself.

Comment: Secondly, you have to have belongs_to :user in Level model too.

Comment: None of your suggestions work/make any difference. Neither does your original answer

Comment: <%arel = Level.includes(:games)%>
   <%= column_chart arel.group('game').sum(:score) %>

Just gives **Association named 'games' was not found on Level; perhaps you misspelled it?**